# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json without maven

Tags: rest

I am creating a rest project, with simple get service. When I use the response type as 'text/HTML' then everything works fine. But I need response in json. I get following error while converting to JSON 'MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json'. I am not using maven for this project. I have attached the web.xml with this question. please help.

Comment: Web.xml----<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.arundemo.rest</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

Answer (score 1):

May be the MIME type default is of type as 'text/HTML' and some of the jar files won't support the MIME type as 'application/json'.Might be the jar file you are using won't have the support for the type you are looking for.

Please check this link where you can get the jar files as you won't seems to implementing the maven usage https://code.google.com/p/genson/